New to Ubuntu and need to run BIND user as non-root
I've used Centos more recently and I've run BIND there.
In Centos, I've made sure to not run the BIND user as root by adding the option in the /etc/sysconfig/named file, and that was pretty straightforward.
What's the best way to avoid running the BIND user as root on Ubuntu?

Please add the version of Ubuntu you are using to the question.

You don't need to do anything to run bind as non-root on Ubuntu.  It will run named as the unprivileged bind user by default.

That would explain why I can't find anything about it.
